# Kafka producer/consumer are opening too many file descriptor

Tags: apache-kafka, centos, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We have a 3 node Kafka cluster deployment with 5 topics and 6 partitions per topic. we have configured the replication factor =3 , we are seeing very strange problem that number of file descriptor have been crossed the ulimit ( what is 50K for our application)

```
As per the lsof command and our analysis 

1. there have 15K established connection from kafka producer/consumer  towards broker and at the same time in thread dump we have observed thousands of entry for kafka 'admin-client-network-thread'

admin-client-network-thread" #224398 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f12ca119800 nid=0x5363 runnable [0x00007f12c4db8000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
- locked <0x00000005e0603238> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
- locked <0x00000005e0603228> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
- locked <0x00000005e0602f08> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:672)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:396)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:238)
- locked <0x00000005e0602dc0> (a org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:214)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:205)
at kafka.admin.AdminClient$$anon$1.run(AdminClient.scala:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


2. As per the lsof output , We have observed 35K entry for pipe and event poll

java    5441 app  374r     FIFO                0,9      0t0  22415240 pipe
java    5441 app  375w     FIFO                0,9      0t0  22415240 pipe
java    5441 app  376u  a_inode               0,10        0      6379 [eventpoll]
java    5441 app  377r     FIFO                0,9      0t0  22473333 pipe
java    5441 app  378r     FIFO                0,9      0t0  28054726 pipe
java    5441 app  379r     FIFO                0,9      0t0  22415241 pipe
java    5441 app  380w     FIFO                0,9      0t0  22415241 pipe
java    5441 app  381u  a_inode               0,10        0      6379 [eventpoll]
java    5441 app  382w     FIFO                0,9      0t0  22473333 pipe
java    5441 app  383u  a_inode               0,10        0      6379 [eventpoll]
java    5441 app  384u  a_inode               0,10        0      6379 [eventpoll]
java    5441 app  385r     FIFO                0,9      0t0  40216087 pipe
java    5441 app  386r     FIFO                0,9      0t0  22483470 pipe


Setup details :- 
apache kafka client :- 1.0.1
Kafka version :- 1.0.1
Open JDK :- java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-1
CentOS version :- CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810

Note:- After restarted VM file descriptor count was able to clear and come to normal count as 1000 
then after few second file descriptor count started to increase and it will reach to 50K (limit) after 
1-week in Idle scenarios.
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to the use of deprecated kafka.admin.AdminClient API. Instead, org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient can be used to obtain similar information from Kafka. This API has equivalent methods and provides the same functionality as legacy API.

With legacy API(kafka.admin.AdminClient API), lots of daemon threads ("admin-client-network-thread") are observed in thread dump. Somehow in legacy API, admin client network threads are not maintained well and you will see lots "admin-client-network-thread" daemon threads are created for each call and none of them will ever terminate. Due to this huge number of file descriptors are observed at the process and system level.

Answer (score 0):

Brokers create and maintain file handles for each log segment files and network connections. The total number could be very huge if the broker hosts many partitions and partition has many log segment files. This applies for the network connection as well.

The number of segment files is the number of partitions multiplied by some number that is dependent on the retention policy. The default retention policy is to start a new segment after one week (or 1GB, whatever occurs first) and to delete a segment when all data in it is more than one week old.

I don't immediately see any possible performance declines caused by setting a large `file-max`, but the page cache miss matters.